# Issue with forkJoin, the code does not run past subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, fork-join

The code below is fetching two values from the database.

This is getting done by using `forkJoin` which I have never used. The reason for using this is because I have a function which requires the two values to be ready before calling the function `this.complexWordIdentification(this.postIWant, this.theHardWords);`

As it is on the ngOnInit, it loads it at the start which is what I want because, in this scenario, I want to load the special words from the database and the text from the database and then run it through a function at the start but that function needs to have those two values which are:
`this.theHardWords` and `this.PostIWant`.

As shown below in the `Observable.forkJoin(` it does not get to the `console.log('first');`. Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      annotation: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(8),
          Validators.maxLength(250)
        ]
      })
    });
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('postId');
    this.annotationService.getWords();
    this.postsService.getPosts();

   Observable.forkJoin(
      this.annotationService.getWordUpdateListener(),
      this.postsService.getPostUpdateListener()
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        // data[0] result from getWordUpdateListener
        this.thewords = data[0];
        this.thewords.map(word => {
          console.log('first');
          this.theHardWords.push(word.word);
          this.wordWithAnnotation.push(word);
        });
        // data[1] result from getPostUpdateListener
        this.posts.map(post => {
          console.log('second');
          if (post.id === this.id) {
            this.postIWant = post.fileText;
          }
        });
        console.log('third');
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.complexWordIdentification(this.postIWant, this.theHardWords);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        // error handling
      }
  );

    this.role = this.authService.getUserRole();
    this.userIsAuthenticated = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    this.authStatus = this.authService
      .getAuthStatus()
      .subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
        this.userIsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
        this.role = this.authService.getUserRole();
      });
    this.isLoading = false;
}
```

If you wish to ask any questions feel free to do so to help answer this question. I would like to add that I am not too experienced...Thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint to see if it goes to that line ? `this.thewords = data[0];`

Comment: @David Yes, even if I move the `console.log(first);` up ontop of `this.thewords = data[0];` it still doesn't show unfortunately, any idea why this could be?

Comment: Not really. Did you check wether any of your services was called when using forkJoin?

Comment: @David How do you check that sorry? Not too experienced in this. I can show you how I used to have my code and it all worked fine, but I had to call the function outside. This code was advised by someone the forkJoin in order to achieve calling the function once `this.postIWant` and `this.theHardWords` were loaded fully.

Comment: Like setting a breakpoint in `this.annotationService.getWordUpdateListener()` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this.

```
forkJoin(
  this.annotationService.getWordUpdateListener(),
  this.postsService.getPostUpdateListener()
).subscribe(
  // Your code
);
```

Check the rxjs [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) of forkJoin.
I've created a small example [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/MichaelKiener95/9ae10a662bdebf6c83e829994a5a40d4).